# ExpandableListView with Content from R.menu

Tags: android, android-listview

i've a problem with handling the ExpandableListView.

I have a tabwidget so i have to extend from TabActivity in my MainAppilcation class.
On each tab there is an other ExpandableListView as Content.
The content should be set with a menu-xml-file.
My menu.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/group1"
      android:title="@string/group1">
        <item android:id="@+id/sub1"
            android:title="@string/sub1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/sub2"
            android:title="@string/sub2" />
        <item android:id="@+id/sub3"
            android:title="@string/sub3" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group2"
      android:title="@string/group2">
        <item android:id="@+id/sub1"
            android:title="@string/sub1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/sub2"
            android:title="@string/sub2" />
        <item android:id="@+id/sub3"
            android:title="@string/sub3" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

The whole content to be shown is static. So it doesn't change dynamicly.

At the End it should look like this:
[image]

Now, here is my Question. 
**How i can set the entries of an ExpandableListView in the xml like this:**

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/ExpList"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:expandableListEntries="@menu/basic" />
```

**Or with a menu-resource to it like this:**

```
ExpandableListView view = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
view.setEntries(R.menu.basic);
```

**If not, how i can read an Menu-file out** (without using simple e.g.FileReader)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with an `R.menu`. I made it with a `values.xml` containing string-arrays. I read out the entries in each string-array to fill 2 kind of Objects.

1) The Group entity.

2) The Child entity.

After that I created an `ExpandableListAdapter extending BaseExpandableListAdapter` and override the methods `getChild()` and `getGroup()` with the getter an setter of my 2 objects.

At the End i had to set the Adapter `ExpandableListAdapter` and to set the indicators with my content.